# Javafx Custom DialogPane Having Border Color Shrinks When Ever A Key Is Pessed

Tags: java, javafx, dialog, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have created a custom dialog in Javafx. The problem I a facing is that, whenever I press any key the dialogpane shrinks in size.

The Code for custom Dialog is as follows

```
package javafxcustomdialog;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.control.DialogPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;


public class JavafxCustomDialog extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
        DialogPane dialogPane = dialog.getDialogPane();
        dialog.setHeaderText(null);
        dialog.setGraphic(null);
        dialog.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        dialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        dialog.getDialogPane().setStyle("-fx-background-color: #fff; -fx-border-color: #e7eaec #e7eaec #e7eaec #e7eaec; -fx-border-width: 6;");

        // Set the button types.
        ButtonType okButtonType = new ButtonType("Ok", ButtonBar.ButtonData.OK_DONE);
        ButtonType cancelButtonType = new ButtonType("Cancel", ButtonBar.ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);
        dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(okButtonType, cancelButtonType);

        // VBox
        VBox alertVBox = new VBox();
        VBox.setVgrow(alertVBox, Priority.ALWAYS);
        alertVBox.setPrefWidth(400.0);
        alertVBox.setSpacing(10);
        Label label = new Label("Enter Some Text");
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        alertVBox.getChildren().addAll(label, textField);
        // END VBox

        dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(alertVBox);
        // Request focus on the username field by default.
        Platform.runLater(() -> textField.requestFocus());

        // result
        Optional<List<String>> result = dialog.showAndWait();
        if (result.isPresent()) {
            System.out.println("Good");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Something is wrong..!!");
        }

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

The Problem is in this line

```
dialog.getDialogPane().setStyle("-fx-background-color: #fff; -fx-border-color: #e7eaec #e7eaec #e7eaec #e7eaec; -fx-border-width: 6;");
```

Screenshot:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For someone who is facing the same issue, the solution is just update your java SE from 8u40 to 8u60 or above.
It is a bug in java SE
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8095678